# HTML - CSS for an image with radio button

Tags: html, css, image, radio-button

I would like to have an image with a radio button under it. The image should be get into a frame whenever the radio button is selected.

I achieved that behaviour but with the radio button must be on top of the image, and I would like to have it under the image.

```
        /* IMAGE STYLES */
        [type=radio] + img {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        /* CHECKED STYLES */
        [type=radio]:checked + img {
            outline: 2px solid #f00;
        }
```

```
<table><tr>
<td>
<label>
        <input id="Answer" name="Answer" type="radio" value="1" />
        <img src="X.jpeg" />
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label>
        <img src="X1.jpeg" />         // here the image does not get the frame
        <input id="Answer" name="Answer" type="radio" value="2" />  
</label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Any idea which CSS would match for the second cell of the table?

Comment: How about changing the display-order with CSS, like using Flexbox' `flex-direction`?

Comment: Try the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator).

Comment: If you maintain proper and matching order in similar elements groups, you might find you don't have these surprise problems.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with jquery but if you want to use pure css you can do something like this:

```
 [type=radio]:checked ~ .[CLASS_OF_THE_IMAGE] {
outline: 2px solid #f00;
}
```